# Azure Function MaxAutoRenewDuration ignored

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Function (Consumption Plan) triggered by a service bus queue.

I set `maxAutoRenewDuration` in `host.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:10:00"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

The expectation is that message lock will be renewed up to 10 minutes.
However, if I look at function execution logs, I see message lock expires every 5 minutes, effectively retriggering the function.

The execution logs:

[image]

As can be seen from the logs, function executes exactly after 5 minutes (when the lock expires). I'd expect to see function being re-triggered every 10 minutes (assuming ofc function execution is not done yet).

This is my function:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(MyFunc))]
public async Task MyFunc(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(queueName: "myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
    Message message,
    ILogger logger,
    ExecutionContext executionContext)
{
    var invocationId = executionContext.InvocationId;

    // long running processing, that sometimes can stretch beyond 5 minutes
    await Process(invocationId, message);
}
```

How can I set auto renew duration, so that message lock being renewed until configured time ?

Azure Function v3, running .net core 3.1. OS: Windows

Comment: There's a [documentation issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/62110) on this topic. Though the official document says `maxAutoRenewDuration` is (quoting) "The maximum duration within which the message lock will be renewed automatically." Which is aligned with what you see.

Comment: Thank you @SeanFeldman! I've seen this issue, and the recommendation is `You should make sure that maxAutoRenewDuration is as long as (or longer) than function timeout.`. So for that reason I have `functionTimeout` equal to 10 minutes to match `maxAutoRenewDuration`. But as can be seen from the logs, message lock expires after 5 minutes, function doesn't time out which makes me think `maxAutoRenewDuration` setting is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that in my case no need to set `MaxAutoRenewDuration`. Revisiting [PeekLock behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior) documentation

> The Functions runtime receives a message in PeekLock mode. It calls
> Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully, or
> calls Abandon if the function fails. **If the function runs longer than
> the PeekLock timeout, the lock is automatically renewed as long as the
> function is running.**

I have `functionTimeout` configured in host.json, which is set to 10 minutes. So as long as function executes, message lock will be automatically renewed. I removed `maxAutoRenewDuration` from host.json and now function doesn't execute after message lock expiration.